# Mongodb merging multiple rows base on computed condition on row value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a sample data like this:

```
[
  { objectId: 1, user: 1, phones: [1, 2], emails: ['a'] },
  { objectId: 2, user: 1, phones: [1, 5], emails: ['a', 'f'] },
  { objectId: 3, user: 1, phones: [8, 9], emails: ['f', 'g'] },
  { objectId: 4, user: 1, phones: [10], emails: ['h'] },
  { objectId: 5, user: 2, phones: [1, 2, 3], emails: ['aa', 'bb', cc'] },
]
```

Now I need to merge all related rows into one on these conditions:

- Have same user
- Have at least either one common phone or email

So output something like this:

```
[
  { objectId: 1, user: 1, phones: [1, 2, 5, 8, 9], emails: ['a', 'f', 'g'] },
  { objectId: 4, user: 1, phones: [10], emails: ['h'] },
  { objectId: 5, user: 2, phones: [1, 2, 3], emails: ['aa', 'bb', cc'] },
]
```

This is what I have came up with so far:

```
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$phones",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        user: "$user",
        phone: "$phones"
      },
      objectIds: {
        $addToSet: "$_id"
      },
      emailsList: {
        $push: "$emails"
      },
      user: { $first: "$user" },
      phones: {
        $first: "$phones"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "emails": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$emailsList",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": { "$setUnion": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  {
    "$project": {
      "emailsList": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$emails",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        user: "$user",
        phone: "$emails"
      },
      objectIdsList: {
        $push: "$objectIds"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "mergedObjectIds": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$objectIdsList",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": { "$setUnion": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And then we have a list of objectIds need to be merged in, then I will merge it all in application code. So is there anyway I can do that in aggregation framework alone, or pipe the result of this aggregate in to the next one

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, these are just the "sets" for each user. So simply unwind both arrays and accumulate via [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) for each of `"phones"` and `"emails"`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$phones" },
  { "$unwind": "$emails" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$user",
    "phones": { "$addToSet": "$phones" },
    "emails": { "$addToSet": "$emails" }
  }}
])
```

Which returns:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "phones" : [ 3, 2, 1 ], "emails" : [ "cc", "bb", "aa" ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "phones" : [ 9, 1, 2, 5, 8 ], "emails" : [ "g", "f", "a" ] }
```

A "set" is not really considered to be "ordered", so if you expect a certain order then you need to sort elsewhere, and probably best in the client.

Any "unique" id's don't really apply here. If anything you would use a different accumulator like [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) or [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/), or maybe [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) depending on what you want, however the only relevant details I see here is the `"user"` for grouping and the other accumulated "set" values.

Even though unwinding multiple arrays produces a "cartesian product" of the other values, it really does not matter when everything being pulled out is as "distinct" values anyway. This typically only matters where you need to "count" elements, and that is something your output is not looking for in the question.

Comment: Thank for your answer but it not what I meant :D.
this is a contact list collected from user device, so user mean the user who has these contact.

I have add more example to clarify these point. All object with objectId (1, 2, 3, 4) have the same user. But only 1, 2 and 3 group together because have common phone/email, 4 still stand alone

Comment: @TrungTínTrần "Read" the answer. You **cannot** have `objectId` in the result as you expect. All your results are "sets" and even with the new line, the code here still returns your expected result 'sans the `objectId` value` which I state you **cannot return** at least in the way you expect. If anything you want the `$max` or `$last` value for that. But you cannot have all of them or by a random pattern.

Comment: Indeed, and let me say thank again for your help. But let me state it again, I don't need objectId in the return, but the grouping criteria is not base on the "user" field alone as in your answer, it need to be in combine of have same user, and at least one common phone or email.

If it cannot be archived by mongo aggregation alone I'm happy to go with my original attempt and done the rest in my application code

Comment: @TrungTínTrần I have no idea what you think you mean by "at least one common phone or email". Nothing in the data or your expected result shows any other link than this being the "collective sets" as determined per user. Your attempt went into a long winded direction of what I'm showing you is exactly the same thing since `$setUnion` returns a "set", and it's also simple to do this over both results as opposed to your attempt. I suggest if you think you mean something else then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and give a clear example to your conditions.

Comment: @TrungTínTrần But at any rate you should never "change your question" after any answer has been provided which actually solves the result you showed by example you were looking for. So if you think you meant something else then the "new question" is the approach to take and simply accept you were shown something which answered the case and that you maybe should have provided a case that can **only** be solved by other conditions if you did mean something else. I'm really not sure however that you actually do mean anything else, and simply just cannot see it at the moment. I call this answered